# Redis HSETNX no key space notification raised

Tags: redis

I was testing Redis key space notification events. I receive a notification for HSET but not when I do a HSETNX. Is this expected? How can I receive an event if a value of a hash field changes?

Thanks,
Sudha

Answer (score 1):

If you can receive `HSET` notifications you configured your notifications correctly.
`HSETNX` will only trigger an event if the field you try to set does not exists. Otherwise, this operation has no effect, and no event will be triggered.